# Equipartition of energy in $n$ dimensions

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, physics, wave-equation

Let $u \in C^2(\mathbb R^n \times [0, \infty))$ be a real solution of the wave equation

$$\begin{cases} \partial_t^2 u - \Delta_x u = 0 & \text{in } \mathbb R^n \times (0, \infty) \\ u(x, 0) = f(x), \quad u_t(x, 0) = g(x) & \text{in } x \in \mathbb R^n, f \in C_c^2(\mathbb R^n), g \in C_c^1(\mathbb R^n) \end{cases}$$

We define $k(t) := \frac 1 2 u_t(x, t)^2 d x$ as the kinetic energy, $p(t) := \frac 1 2 |\nabla_x u(x, t)^2| d x$ as the potential energy, and $e(t) := p(t) + k(t)$ as the total energy. I now want to show that $e(t)$ is constant on $[0, \infty)$.

Now I did find some threads like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1081227/equipartition-of-energy/2468310#2468310) where this question is explored and answered for the case $n = 1$, but I'm not sure if the argument carries over the same for higher dimensions. Like in the answer given there, I would start with $\frac d{dt} e(t)$ and then use the Leibniz rule/differential rule for parameter integrals to pull the $\frac d{dt}$ into the integral, i.e.

$$\frac d{dt} e(t) = \frac 1 2 \int_{\mathbb R^n} \frac d{dt} \left( u_t(x, t)^2 d x + |\nabla_x u(x, t)|^2 \right) d x$$

which would get me

$$= \frac 1 2 \int_{\mathbb R^n} \left( 2 u_t u_{t t} d x + \frac d{dt} |\nabla_x u(x, t)|^2 \right) d x  $$

but my problem is, how do I now handle the $\frac d{dt} |\nabla_x u(x, t)|^2$-term? Unlike in the other answer where $x$ has only one component, I'm not sure where to go from here or what to make of it.

What confuses me is that I'm also given the hint that I might first want to show: for any $t_0 > 0$, there exists a compact set $K \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ so that $\mathrm{supp} u(\cdot, t) \subseteq K$ for all $t \in [0, t_0]$. But I'm not sure what for I would actually need this.

Comment: To compute the derivative, write $|\nabla u|^2=\sum_{j=1}^n (\partial_{x_j} u)^2$. Concerning the compactness of the support, who told you that the integral is finite, in the first place? And in the second place, compactly supported functions make for easier integration by parts, since boundary terms vanish.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thank you. Ok I see, showing the fact regarding the compactness of $\mathrm{supp} u(\cdot, t)$ gives me the existence of the integral. How could I go about showing that (the compactness of this support) if I may ask?

Comment: That's a basic property of the wave equation, called *finite speed of propagation*.

Answer (score 2):

The correct replacement for $(u^2_x)_t = 2u_xu_{xt}$ is $$ \partial_t |\nabla u|^2 = 2\nabla u\cdot\nabla u_t $$
In fact this follows from the 1D rule because for any vector valued function $f=(f_1(t),\dots,f_n(t))$
$$ \partial_t |f|^2 =\partial_t \sum_{i}f_i^2 = \sum_i \partial_t (f_i^2)=2∑f_i\partial_tf_i = 2f\cdot\partial_t f$$
One concludes what you want by integration by parts, since $\int_{ℝ^n} \nabla a \cdot \vec{b} = -\int_{ℝ^n} a\nabla\cdot \vec{b}$.